# Error in accessing wordpress backend

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, authentication

Here is my [site url](http://fanzplanet.com/fp/)

But once I type `http://fanzplanet.com/fp/wp-admin/`
it already redirects to

```
http://127.0.0.1/fanz/wp-login.php
```

which is my local host login.How can I change this?

Here is my `.htaccess` file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /fp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Seems like it is working fine.
What went wrong?Please help me.

Comment: Where that was working before ? On the local machine ?!
Try removing the 127.0.0.1 by the wp baseurl.

Comment: Yeah on local machine

Comment: I think that this article will help you http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/

WP is a complex system and it's not going to work with only moving some files around :)

Answer (score 0):

Open up your wp-config.php and add the following lines:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://yourdomain.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://yourdomain.com' );
```

You could open your options table in the database instead and make these changes but this is simpler to explain.